# formatting and converting in java

Tags: java, formatting, casting

I have few small basic problems :

How to format :

```
int i = 456;
```

to give output :

```
""00000456"
```

? I've tried %08d but it's not working. Next thing is a problem with conversion and then formatting. I have side and height of triangle, let's say int's 4,7, and 7 is the height. From formula for field we know that F=1/2(a*h). So how to get F as float, with precision up to 10 places ?

```
float f = a*h;
```

works fine, but multiplying it by 0.5 gives error and by 1/2 returns 0.

Comment: You should really ask two questions in two posts rather than combining them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to use String.format.

```
    String fs = String.format("%08d", this.id);
    return fs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NumberFormat class see [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/numberformat.html) or [that](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-number-format/) explanation, the [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class or String.format

Answer (score 0):

> How to format :
>
> int i = 456; to give output :
>
> "00000456"

System.out.printf("%08d", i) can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

1/2 is an integer expression, it will not be automatically converted to a float.

1/2 should be one of: 1.0f/2.0f, 1.0f/2, 1/2.0f, (float)1/(float)2, (float)1/2, 1/(float)2, float-variable/float-variable, float-variable/int-variable, int-variable/float-variable, ... you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Should be `%.08d` instead of `%08d`, secondly try multiplying by `0.5f` instead.